# Missing Files app from dash / application switcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, 16.04, application-switcher

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (very happy with it so far), but I am facing a really weird issue. It's not impossible that I have changed a setting somewhere to break it, but I cannot find such a setting anywhere.

When I launch the Files application (Nautilus) I do not see the application in the launcher (the left panel). When I Alt+Tab I see all other apps (except minimized), but Files is also missing. The app is not minimized.

Comment: Are you missing the `Files` icon *at all*, or are windows not appearing under the icon?

Comment: I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1646420

Answer (score 9):

If you open Nautilus and navigate to `/usr/share/applications` you will see some files named 'Files'. In the Nautilus window you will not see their filenames unfortunately you will see this:

[image]

If you *first* drag each file onto a `gedit` window you will be able to identify the files as:

1. `nautilus.desktop`
2. `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`
3. `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

All you need to do is to *drag* the one named `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` over onto your left panel launcher and simply drop it there. All should be well :)

Comment: Nope, in 16.04, the one you need is `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks, I have replaced the image and corrected the selected file...

Comment: This is partially solving the problem. It works when the icon is in the HUD, but I don't want to keep it pinned there. I like to have it clean.

Comment: Thanks so much. This fixed my problem after I uninstalled Nemo. Ta-da!

Comment: @AlexK Great news :)