# Unity, Files/Nautilus doesn't appear on alt+tab switcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, application-switcher

When I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to change between windows, the  "Files" window doesn't appear. It's really annoying because when I try to access the previously opened "Files" window, I have to minimize everything or open another "Files" process so I end the day with a lot of opened "Files" instances.

Comment: So it has been said you fixed it.  So the core of your question is what ?

Comment: Becouse the solution make no sense. Why I need nautilus in the app dash to make it appear on the switcher?.

Comment: A posible solution is explained in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769063/missing-files-app-from-dash-application-switcher) link. It works for me.

Comment: That's what the link I provided do @maiky_forrester, but I'm not really happy with that :(

Comment: @lcjury  I strongly believe this is a bug, which probably should be reported to the developers. Otherwise, there's no valid explanation as to why it behaves that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Nautilus app to the left panel launcher and now it appears on the application switcher.