# Ubuntu 16.04 : Nautilus not shown in Unity left side menu or in alt-tab

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus

I have Ubuntu X64 16.04 on my system. This was an upgrade from 15.10. The upgrade was successful, but now I am unable to see Nautilus in in alt-tab and an already opened instance cannot be seen. Because of this, I have to open a new instance every time. Kinda tedious as if I have some location opened, it's forgotten as soon as I go in some other app. Check out the screenshot. As you can see in the screenshot, in the left side menu, there are always these small white arrows which indicate the app is open, but it does not happen with Nautilus.

[image]

I have tried to purge nautilis, reinstall it, then drag-dropped it from applications, but as soon as I quit Nautilus, the same problem is back again.

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

*Update*

Output for `killall nautilus && nautilus`

```
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Permission denied
net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

Comment: Did you tried re-installation with another setup.

Comment: @HarshalBenake : Reinstallation of? I don't want to reinstall entire Ubuntu OS for this...if that's what you mean. This is not solving the problem, but eliminating it.

Comment: Did you try to `killall nautilus && nautilus`? Does the problem happen also for the guest user?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto : I just tried it, same result. Didn't try with guest user. I have some console output, which I am pasting in main post. Moment please.

Comment: OK. IMHO the Samba error is not related here, but please try with the guest user to check if it works there.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto : I thought the same, but thought will post it. Same issue with guest user. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have suggestions for this. :( I see you have a phone connected. If you click over it on the launcher, do you see the white triangle?

Comment: A posible solution in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769063/missing-files-app-from-dash-application-switcher) link.
It works for me.